# What does postProcessBeforeInitialization means in Spring BeanPostProcessor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

In XML file

```
<bean id="triangle" class="com.company.aop.model.Triangle">
    <property name="name" value="myTriangle"></property>
</bean>

<bean class="com.company.aop.DisplayNameBeanPostProcessor"></bean>
```

In DisplayNameBeanPostProcessor.java class

```
public class DisplayNameBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor{

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(bean instanceof Triangle) {
//          System.out.println("Tr "+(((Triangle) bean).getName().toString()));
            System.out.println("I am after intialisation");
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(bean instanceof Triangle) {
            System.out.println("Tr "+(((Triangle) bean).getName().toString()));
        }
        return bean;
    }

}
```

Now when i run this code, it goes to postProcessBeforeInitialization() method with argument bean and beanName and prints the message "myTriangle". This bean has information like its name field with value "myTriangle" in my case. But the method signature says that it is before initialisation then what is this bean that has been passed into it if it has not been initialised yet ?
And what is the difference between

```
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
```

and

```
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
```

Why this line

```
System.out.println("Tr "+(((Triangle) bean).getName().toString()));
```

prints the name in method postProcessBeforeInitialization if the method has been called before initialisation ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can refer to the section 5.8.1 of the Spring docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension). The key point here is that the "postProcessBeforeInitialization" should be read as "postProcessBeforeInitializationCallback" and "postProcessAfterInitialization" should be read as "postProcessAfterInitializationCallback". So these are pre and post processeors after the before/after initialization callback are run by the Spring container on the bean. This is what is conveyed in the docs of these methods [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html#postProcessAfterInitialization-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-) too.

> Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean,
>                                          String beanName)
>                                   throws BeansException
>
> Apply this BeanPostProcessor to the given new bean instance before any
>   bean initialization callbacks (like InitializingBean's
>   afterPropertiesSet or a custom init-method). The bean will already be
>   populated with property values.

Note it says that "*The bean will already be populated with property values*".
Similarly

> Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean,
>                                         String beanName)
>                                  throws BeansException
>
> Apply this BeanPostProcessor to the given new bean instance after any
>   bean initialization callbacks (like InitializingBean's
>   afterPropertiesSet or a custom init-method). The bean will already be
>   populated with property values.

Comment: Now in the case below beanFactory is passed in argument whereas name of function is postProcessBeanFactory and that means bean factory should be initialised after this postprocessor? 

`public class DisplayNameBeanPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor{`
`@Override`
 `public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory)`
   `throws BeansException {`
`}}`

Answer (score 3):

BeanPostProcessor beans are a special kind of beans that get created before any other beans and interact with newly created beans. The `postProcessBeforeInitialization`  and `postProcessAfterInitialization` are applied on any other bean created by spring.

**But the method signature says that it is before initialisation then what is this bean that has been passed into it if it has not been initialised yet ?**

The initialization here refers to calling an init method of your *triangle* bean, so the before and post calls wrap the call on the init method of the bean. Prior to that, the constructor and setter injections are already performed, that is why the bean has actual values.